# Google developers API 2 access

Tags: android, api, review

We sent request to this API

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/com.instagram.android/reviews

And this is the error we are getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "androidpublisher", 
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
        "reason": "projectNotLinked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone help us?

Comment: Please post examples of the code used to create & receive the request.

Comment: we used google api playground at this address (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) with my gmail account.

step 1: select & authorize APIs: From the list we selcted google play developer API v2
Step2: Exchange authorization code for tokens
Step 3: we select "list reviews" from list possible options and send the request